# Galaxy tab 2 7" does not fit sw600dp?

Tags: android

Everywhere in Android documentation I can ready that I have to use sw600dp for 7 inch tablets, but this does not seem to be true, because Galaxy Tab 2 7" has 546dp for its smallest width.

http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_2_7_0_p3100-4543.php

dp = 600 / (170 / 160) = 546

Should I use sw500dp in my layouts instead?

Comment: your link is related to the 10" version

Comment: njzk2, fixed it. Calculations were still correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android device pixel densities are classified in [buckets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

[image: density buckets]

While the Galaxy Tab 2 screen may actually be 170 dpi, that falls within the range of `mdpi` which translates to 160 dpi being used in practice for `dp` calculations. The device should still have a `600dp` width.

Comment: Cannot find specific place in documentation where are these range borders defined. Where does mdpi end and hdpi start, for instance?

Comment: There are no specifics. Note the overlap in buckets in the charts.

Comment: also, i found a few years ago that the first Tab was ~130dpi but declared itself hdpi...